# $XOR$ function rank of matrices $ $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrices $M_1,M_2\in\Bbb Z^{n\times n}$ with ranks $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively.

What is the rank of the matrix $M=M_1\oplus M_2\in\Bbb Z^{n\times n}$ (not $\Bbb F_2^{n\times n}$) which is defined by:

$M_{ij}=-1\iff M_{1,ij}+M_{2,ij}\equiv 1\bmod 2$

$M_{ij}=+1\iff M_{1,ij}+M_{2,ij}\equiv 0\bmod 2$?

Note $M_1+M_2$ has rank at most $r_1+r_2$.

Comment: Are you sure about the last part?
Take for example
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\oplus
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which has rank $3$. Or what is meant by rank here?

Comment: yes last part is $+$ not $\oplus$.

Comment: True, but it seems hard though to bound the rank of such a sum anyway. Have you tried running some numerical experiment?